# Is there a faster to Dissolve Vertices for a sims model? (Sims 4 Fixing Long Hair)

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

I love the idea that I'm able to use the "Sims 4 ripper" to import my favorite Sims that I created in the Sims 4 into Blender and they look even more amazing in Cycles. However, I was told that its best that my sims should have short hair if I'm going to be importing them to Blender and I see why this person said that... ***(Continue reading down below)***

[image]

[image]

Every time I import sims with long hair, the hair comes out looking like the first picture with some dark shade boxes or whatever this is? Also, depending on the type of hair it comes out even more worse then before unless the hair is short like the 2nd picture...

Long hair works 100% with no problem in Eevee, but in Cycles, its hell on earth!

However, I found away to fix the issue by:

Step 1: Set the Render Engine to "Cycles" then for viewport shading have it on "Rendered" and turn off the lights!

[image]

Step 2: Click on the model and go into edit mode and click on "face select".

[image]

Step 3: Hold shift and begin clicking all over the dark areas that is now a bit lighter. Basically, still noticeable.

[image]

Step 4: Once you got every single dark shade or shadows selected, you are going to delete them by pressing the delete key (Button) on your keyboard and you are going to select "Dissolve Vertices".

Now it should come out looking NORMAL!!!

[image]

See the difference? I want to make this process more easier and quicker for everyone that been dying to import their sims with long hair in Blender while having the render engine set on Cycles.

Depending on the hair and how long it is and how many layers it has, it might take like a good 10 to 15 minutes maybe less or longer... However, if there is a faster way of doing this. I would love to hear your feedback on it. It would honestly be VERY helpful to me and the wonderful Sims community.

Here's a link to the Blender File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18Y5ZrimaF9qeeu5MBjY_wBsFGioVTl9p/view?usp=drive_link

It comes with the model and textures just in case.

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: It looks a bit like Z-fighting as if there were duplicate faces. However how to select them the easiest way and getting rid of them depends a lot on how the geometry really is in these areas. So if you could upload a file with a problematic model as Rick suggested (at least a file which has the hair mesh in it) it would help to find out best practices.

Comment: The link to the Blender file is now Available. Its located at the very bottom of the last image. Thank you for taking the time to check it out and giving me some good advise.

Comment: the link you provided requires access rights.

Comment: The link should be available now Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, it is Z-fighting. This means that there are two or more faces lying directly in the same plane or very close together, so that the render engine has difficulties determining the Z depth from the camera and does not know which face to render in front of the other. This problem occurs only in *Cycles* because *Eevee* is not a raytracing engine.

Take a look at the following example: I select one of the hair strands by hovering my mouse over it and pressing <kbd>L</kbd> to select only connected geometry:

[image: select front geometry]

You can already see where grey unselected parts show through the orange selected parts, that there could be some duplicate geometry. If I now hide the selection with <kbd>H</kbd>, there still is a hair strand in place which is (almost) identical:

[image: remaining geometry]

The problem is, while most of the time identical duplicates are quite easy to fix by selecting all with <kbd>A</kbd> and then merging by distance with <kbd>M</kbd>, this does not work here because if you compare both strands isolated separately, you see that one of them has a quite regular triangle geometry while the other is lacking vertices and therefore also edges inbetween. This means, merging those two strands will only merge some of the vertices, but since many of them create different faces, those faces will not be merged and stay separate and overlaying each other and so keep Z-fighting.

[image: strand comparison]

I do not know if this is the unaltered mesh you get from The Sims, but if so the problem is that because of the discrepancies in the overlaying meshes, the usual automatic cleanup methods do not work here - which comes down to having to clean it up manually. I mean, if you hover your mouse over a part and press <kbd>L</kbd> like I did, you do not have to select each face one by one but can select complete strands.

Then you could delete them and keep only the underlying duplicate. However, the strands in the example had the regular tri-faced one on top i.e. it gets selected first, so if you delete it you would keep the more messy one. Of course you could select the "good" one, hide it with <kbd>H</kbd> and then select the messy one afterwards and delete it.

Unfortunately all this is tedious, manual work. At least I do not see any good way to do it, maybe someone else has an idea. And I don't know if there are settings upon extracting the models which can avoid these duplicate faces. Most likely the reason for the mesh to be like that is that game engines often work with backface culling, which means a face would be invisible if seen from the backside. The body of the model is a closed mesh so you always see the frontside of the faces, hence no need for duplicate faces. The hair strands however are just row of flat faces, so if would look at them from the backside they would disappear. And that's why the hair strands are duplicated, one version to look at from the front, one version to look at from behind - as you can see if you enable the *Face Orientation* overlay, the regular tri strand shows the frontside (blue), the other strand shows the backside (red):

[image: front- and backside]